# WCF Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled

Tags: wcf, web, metadata, config

I am struggling to display metadata while using WCF.

I have looked all over the place. I'm not sure if it is a setting in my web.config file, or my actual service is not working properly. But I get the "Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled." page when I debug.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="myWebHttp"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EDSCoastmap">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttp">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="jsonWebHttp">
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="EDSCoastmap" name="EDS_CoastmapRest.EDSCoastmap">
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" binding="webHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="myWebHttp" contract="EDS_CoastmapRest.IEDSCoastmap" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your service doesn't have SOAP endpoint so there are no valid metadata to be exposed. You don't need neither `serviceMetadata` behavior or MEX endpoint if you don't have SOAP service.

Btw. how do you debug the service?

Comment: I am trying to create a rest service. Unfortunately, I am building on a soap service that was created initially.

Comment: The REST service in WCF doesn't have any description like WSDL so it also doesn't need metadata publication.